# Shuffle cells within a row using AWK

Tags: awk, shuffle

I'm trying to shuffle all the columns that have a slash in it (thus everything from the 5th column). However, I'm not getting there, shuffling row's is easy but cells within a row I just can' t figure it out. The reshuffling has to be performed on every row individually.

This the data that I have (here the fiels are ordened, 1/1 then 1/0 etc..)

chr1   10967   A   T   1/1   1/1   1/1   1/0   1/0   1/0  0/0   1/.   1/.   0/.   0/.   ./.   ./.
chr1   13241   C   G   1/1   1/1   1/1   1/1   1/1   1/0  1/0   1/.   1/.   1/.   1/.   0/.   ./.

And I'd like to randomize this order (so not the actual content of the fields but just their position in the row)

chr1   10967   A   T   1/0   1/.   1/1   1/1   1/0   1/1   0/0   1/.   0/.   0/.   ./.   ./.   1/0   
chr1   13241   C   G   ./.   1/1   1/1   1/1   1/1   1/1   1/0  1/0   1/.   1/.   1/.   1/.   0/.

(I'm not such a great randomizer myself but the idea is clear I hope)

Does anyone have an idea how to do such a thing in AWK/GAWK/NAWK (I already have a huge AWK script in which I'd like to incorporate it)? A script that I found here nicely randomizes rows but that not exactly what I'm trying to do... This script by the way comes from https://stackoverflow.com/users/131527/ghostdog74

```
BEGIN{srand() }
{ lines[++d]=$0 }
END{
    while (1){
if (e==d) {break}
    RANDOM = int(1 + rand() * d)
    if ( RANDOM in lines  ){
        print lines[RANDOM]
        delete lines[RANDOM]
        ++e
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are the fields to be randomized always the fifth through the seventeenth? Or are there different numbers of fields in different rows or some rows where not all the fields past the first four qualify? Does each row need to be randomized differently, or would just randomizing the columns be acceptable?

Comment: @twalberg Thanks for your comments. It's always the 5th column till the final column and the numbers of columns is the same in every row (this is just an example, my actual file has 108 columns and over 10^9 rows). Every row needs to be randomized differently, randomizing the columns if unfortunately of no use. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Kent, well I could but it makes it way more complex. Inside my AWK script there's a function that builds all these rows within a file that also contains other type of rows. If I can stay kind of within the borders of the function I don't have to care about the other rows. And being such a large file I think it'd speed up the process if I don't have to go through all the rows twice.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN{srand();OFS="   "} {for(i=5;i<=NF;i++) {k=int((NF-4)*rand()+5); j=$k; $k=$i; $i=j;} print;}' input.txt
```

input:

```
chr1   10967   A   T   1/1   1/1   1/1   1/0   1/0   1/0  0/0   1/.   1/.   0/.   0/.   ./.   ./.
chr1   13241   C   G   1/1   1/1   1/1   1/1   1/1   1/0  1/0   1/.   1/.   1/.   1/.   0/.   ./.
```

output:

```
chr1   10967   A   T   ./.   1/1   1/0   1/1   1/1   0/.   1/0   1/.   1/0   0/.   ./.   1/.   0/0
chr1   13241   C   G   1/1   ./.   1/0   1/0   1/.   1/1   1/1   1/.   1/1   0/.   1/1   1/.   1/.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one way, with gawk's `asorti()`, I didn't apply it with your example, but I don't think it is a big problem for you:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[i]=$i}
END{for(i in a)
        {
        x = sprintf("%.77f",rand())
        t[x] = a[i]
        }
        asorti(t,m)
        for(j=1;j<=length(m);j++)printf "%s%s", t[m[j]], (j==length(m)?"\n":FS)
}'
```

test with `1-17`:

```
kent$  seq -s ' ' 17|awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[i]=$i}
END{for(i in a)
        {
        x = sprintf("%.77f",rand())
        t[x] = a[i]
        }
        asorti(t,m)
        for(j=1;j<=length(m);j++)printf "%s%s", t[m[j]], (j==length(m)?"\n":FS)
}'
10 4 8 6 16 1 14 2 11 9 12 5 17 7 3 15 13
```

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be slow, but it should accomplish what you want:

```
BEGIN {srand()}
{ for (i = 5; i <= NF; ++i)
    a[rand()] = $i
  asort(a)
  printf "%s %s %s %s", $1, $2, $3, $4
  for (i = 1; i < NF-5)
     printf " %s", a[i]
  printf "\n"
  delete a
}
```

I haven't actually tested it, so it may not be 100% correct, but the basic idea is to put each of the fields to be randomized into an array with a random index, then sort the array and output the result.